# How to make two arrays of coordinates, concentric squares

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create two arrays of coordinates which are two areas of concentric squares or even circles (squares are the only ones I was able to think off and actually attempt to make, but in the beginning and ultimately I wanted simple squared concentric circles).

Simply put, for `n<m` to get areas of coordinates `(m*2-n*2)` and `(n*2)`.

I've been trying multiple 'for' loops like:

```
a,b=(m-n)/2,(m-(m-n)/2)
ncrd,coord=[],[]
x,y=range(0,m*10,10),range(0,m*10,10)
k,l=0,0
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        coord.append([0,0])
        coord[k]=[x[i],y[j]]
        k+=1
for i in range((m-n)/2,m-(m-n)/2):
    for j in range((m-n)/2,m-(m-n)/2):
        ncrd.append([0,0])
        ncrd[l]=coord[i*m+j]
        l+=1
    coord[i*m:i*m+j]=[]
    rnd.shuffle(coord),rnd.shuffle(ncrd)
```

I'm pretty sure it's wrong, because it doesn't work and the logic isn't sound. Been trying to write it out mathematically, but drawing blanks.

In summation: need to create on giant m*m array ([x,y]) and cut out a chunk of it in the middle and assign that to another value. In the code above it was `coord` and `ncrd`.

Edit: Forgot to mention, that `m` and `n` are entered at the start of the program, so they are not specific values and can range from 3 to any possible value that my computer can take.

Comment: You mention making concentric shapes, but what should the radius be of each shape? Should one have twice the radius of the other? Should their radii be independently set?

Comment: @JasonPearson I'm not sure, I just need the first area to have (n) coordinate values, but spaced at least by 5, and the outside area to have (m-n) coordinate values, but spaced by at least 10. I really haven't thought this through yet, but I know that it would look the best for my plot.

Comment: @JasonPearson also sorry, forgot to mention in OP, will edit now: the values 'm' and 'n' are chosen by the user, so I need to find a way to make a code that makes this kind of stuff with any positive whole number

Comment: Should coordinates on the boundary between the inner square and the outer square be included in the list of coordinates of the inner square, the list of coordinates of the other square , or both?

Comment: @JohnColeman either the first or the second option, because the points in the outer and inner squares are going to be assigned specific values(nodes), so the boundary has to belong to one of the squares, not both. To which square won't play that big a role I think.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these line would work for concentric square areas. For circular ones, you'd need to change the logical expression accordingly.

Note: The shuffling of the results at the end has been left out.

```
m, n = 9, 5
lo = (m-n) // 2
hi = m-lo-1

coords, ncoords = [], []
for x in range(m):
    for y in range(m):
        (ncoords if (lo <= x <= hi) and (lo <= y <= hi) else coords).append((x, y))

print(coords)
print(ncoords)
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?